# Weighting function for favorites

Tags: math

I've got a list of items. Users can occasionally select them. Now I want to order the items by their popularity. What's a good weighting function for that?

Constraints:

- The weight should be in [0,1)
- Recursive calculation is prefered (not required)
- Newer events must have more influence than old ones.
- I'd favor approved functions. As I've developped something like this once and it worked not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a counter of votes per item, you can use a 'fading constant' in order to make older votes "fade away" with time. Something like:

`Nvotes(i) = IsClicked(i) + Nvotes(i) * Kfade`

where:  `0 < Kfade < 1`

Thus, whenever a new click is intercepted, all counters are advanced where only the selected item is incremented by 1.

EDIT: Since the total is less than 1, you may want to normalize Nvotes by the total number of clicks so far.

Comment: This one looks nice, I'll give it a try.

Comment: It is more or less a 1-tap IIR filter.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I want to order the items by their popularity.

So you order by the number of times some user selected the item.

> The weight should be in `[0,1)`.

Fine, divide by the total number of times some user selected some item plus one.

> Recursive calculation is prefered

Why? Maybe I'm missing the point of what you're trying to do because otherwise this constraint is lost on me.

Edit:

Responding to your edit, try

```
sum ( 1 / age of vote ) / age of item
```

the sum being taken over all votes for a given item.

Comment: Well, that's too simple, I want recent clicks to have more influence than older ones. Maybe last year item A was clicked 10.000 times, but today something happend and item B is clicked 1000 times, then item B should be on top.

Comment: @Michael Stoll: But see, you didn't say anything that suggested that. You just said "by [...] popularity."

Comment: @Jason: Yes, this one would be better, but I can't calculate that much every time. That's why I added the "recursive" constraint.

Comment: @Michael Stoll: Don't know what to tell you, if you want the votes to age then you need to recalculate every time. Your constraints demand that. The reason most popularity algorithms don't take into consideration age of the vote is exactly for the reason of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list `items` of the items that need sorting. Let each item have a score. Keep a list `clicks` of the N most recent clicks, in order of decreasing recency. Each item can appear more than once in the list. Choose a constant `fade` a little smaller than 1. Then do:

```
for item in items:
    item.score = 0.0
bonus = 1.0
for item in clicks:
    item.score += bonus
    bonus *= fade
```

Now sort the items by score, highest first.

The score isn't in the range 0 to 1, but i don't see why you actually need that. It would be straightforward to normalise the scores afterwards.

This isn't recursive, but it's straightforward to put in recursive form.

This isn't a known algorithm. I don't know of any known algorithms for this except move-to-front, which is almost certainly more aggressive than you want.